# How can I get javascript to service event queue in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I have a function that needs to wait until a promise is resolved before returning a value. Unfortunately, simply using a while loop and checking if the promise is resolved hogs the thread and won't let my setTimeout function execute it's callback. The only solution I can think of is to tell js to service the event queue if my d.promise has not been resolved to true. Bellow is my code:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var Q = require('q');

var h = function(x,y,z, callback) {

  setTimeout(function(){
    // This never logs to my terminal
    console.log(x + y + z);
    callback();
  }, 1000);
};

var b = function(x,y,z, callback) {
  console.log(x * y * z);
  callback();
};

chain = function(args, f) {
  var index;
  if( (index = _.indexOf(args,'cb')) < 0 ) {
          f.apply(null,args);
  } else {
      return {
        chain: function(newArgs, fxn) {
          var d = Q.defer();
          args[index] = function() {
            d.resolve(true);
          };
          f.apply(null,args);
          // Don't return until callback is resolved.
          while(d.promise.valueOf() != true){
            // Since the thread is hogged by this loop, I'd like
            // to tell it to manually service my event/function queue
            // so that setTimeout works while this loop polls.

            // This setTimeout will never execute the callback
            setTimeout(function(){console.log('hi');},5);
          };
          return chain(newArgs, fxn);
        }
      }
  }
}

chain([2,2,3,'cb'], h ).
chain([2,5,3, 'cb'], b).
chain([2,1,3,'cb'], h ).
chain([2,2,5, 'cb'], b).
chain([6,6,6, function() {console.log('ok');}], b);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises continue with `.then` kind of like regular synchronous code continues with `;`

So, in order to wait for a promise to resolve, you don't do `while(promiseNotResolved)`, instead, you do:

```
promise().then(function(value){
    //code that runs once the promise is resolved
});
```

Comment: Alright, I guess then I'll have to change my strategy. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Student also note that you should not implement chaining yourself, this is what `.then` does, and consider promisifying that `h` function.

Comment: The difficulty behind this issue that I'm trying to solve is that I don't have the luxury of working with promises. I'm working with code that uses callbacks for synchronization and I was hoping to build something to easily chain it together without callback hell. I can use promises in my library, but I can't assume they will.

Comment: @Mr.Student promisifying an API or nodeifying it is trivial with libraries like Bluebird. You don't have to assume anything anymore :)